# Flink - Create BroadcastStream from database properties

Tags: java, database, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have to create a BroadcastStream to be able to change the properties on the database and see the application of these properties in real time on the application.
The problems I have are 2:

1) When I read the database I need to have all the lines at the same time, via resultSet, HashMap or anything that can contain a structure of the type key-value, as some properties depend on other properties, so I cannot process them individually.
The structure of my MapStateDescriptor will be:

```
//String = topic name
//TopicProperties = object containing all the topic properties
MapStateDescriptor<String, TopicProperties> propertiesStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<String, TopicProperties>("properties", 
                                                                                                                        BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                                                                                                                        BasicTypeInfo.of(new TypeHint<TopicProperties>() {}));

BroadcastStream<Row> propertiesBroadcastStream = env.createInput(JDBCInputFormat)
                                                    .map(new TopicPropertiesDbMapper()
                                                    .broadcast(propertiesStateDescriptor);
```

TopicPropertiesDbMapper converts what JDBCInputFormat returns to the String structure, TopicProperties.
The problem is that it is processed one row at a time, but I need to process them all together, as mentioned above.

2) Repeat the reading of the properties and update the BroadcastStream once an hour.

---

I specify that I have already made a version of the one above, but with the reading of the properties from file, through:

```
readFile (FileInputFormat, path file, FileProcessingMode, milliseconds of interval for re-reading)
```

it is working and I solved the two problems listed above for the database case with:

1) Set "unsplittable" flag of the FileInputFormat class to "true";

2) FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to have read the properties via the Flink?

Comment: Yes, I have to read them through Flink because I have to create a BroadcastStream in order to see in real time the change of properties applied to the DataStream.

The use of BroadcastStream is the official way of being able to apply dynamic properties to DataStream (as the documentation also says).

In fact, if you do otherwise, the DataStream does not see the changes.
I don't know how flink works internally, but I think it is optimized for processing speed, so I believe that the architecture of the streams and the objects needed to make them work cannot vary.

Comment: Yeah, but have You thought to create a service/job that would periodically publish the  db properties to file/kafka ??? This should be easier to achieve and perhaps more predictable.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this solution, I thought there was some object to do this directly (example as for reading properties from file).
However in the end to hurry I did as you suggested.
Thanks so much :)